# Is there free parking in Springdale, UT, USA?

Tags: automobiles, national-parks, utah

I will be visiting Zion National Park in September. I read that the best option is to stay in Springdale and simply walk to a shuttle bus stop, leaving your car at the hostel. However, accommodation in Springdale is pretty expensive and I decided to stay in St. George instead and drive to Springdale in the morning.

Is there a problem leaving your car somewhere in Springdale?

How hard is it to find a free parking stop?

Do I have to arrive "at the crack of dawn" to find a spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you arrive early enough you can park at the visitor center. But it is often full before 10 am. So, if it is full, you'll have to backtrack into town:

The National Park Service has a [map of park & ride areas in Springdale](https://web.archive.org/web/20170404091343/https://www.nps.gov/zion/planyourvisit/upload/Springdale%20Shuttle%20Parking%20Map.pdf) which you may be able to use. Some of these are standalone park and ride facilities; others are sections of hotel or local business parking lots, or adjacent to them. In these cases be sure to follow the Park & Ride signs (which unfortunately are fairly small and can be hard to spot) and park in the marked areas. This map also shows where the [town shuttle](https://www.springdaletown.com/320/Shuttle) stops.

The Park & Ride sign looks like this:

[image: Zion National Park Park & Ride Sign]

There is also street parking on parts of Zion Park Blvd., but don't count on finding an open space.

Comment: In order to use this shuttle do I need the ticket to the park?

Comment: @kch There are _two_ shuttles: The town shuttle and the park shuttle. The town shuttle is free and will take you to the park entrance from wherever you leave your car in town. Then you pay to get in to the park, and take the park shuttle from there. You don't need any ticket to use the town shuttle.